# Uneditable source files and shortcuts changed while debugging

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I'm using "Code Gear Delphi 2007", while debugging (Run F9, button with play icon), I can't type any char into source files. 
Furthermore, some of default shortcuts (like copy CTRL+C, paste CTRL+V...) are automatically switched to different values:

[image]

When the execution is stopped (Program reset CTRL+F2, button with stop icon), all problems disappear.
How could I reset my IDE as it was before these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have most likely changed the Debugger Options to Map TD32 keystrokes on run and Mark Buffers read-only on run.

[image: Debugger Options]